# Kendo UI numeric text box setting min value

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

When I set min value for a `KendoNumericTextBox`, it automatically changes to the minimum value, instead of showing error saying that need to have minimum value. How do I change the behavior?

```
var numericBox = $("#numeric_" + attrObj.AttributeId).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
numericBox.min(5);
numericBox.validationMessage = "Please enter value 5 and above";
```

So when I enter `3` for example in the above `numberBox`, but it is supposed to give an error saying `"Please enter value 5 and above"`. Instead the value of the box changes to `5` and no error is shown.

Is there any way I can change this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the "by design" behavior. The numeric textbox doesn't show any messages on its own. It is jut not its business. If you wan't to show a message use validation. Here is an example showing that: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/validator/index.html